# How to parse a simple url response in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, url

I am trying to parse a simple response from the server and use its values.

I was able to get the required information as follows:

**The actual response :**

```
AccountID=0&Authenticated=1&ResponseCode=0&ResponseText=Success
```

What I need is separate values for :

- **AccountID**
- **Authenticated**
- **ResponseCode**
- **ResponseText**

**My code so far :**

```
$tempValue = explode("\n", $response);

foreach($tempValue as $row => $data)          
{    
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode('&', $data);

    $row_internal = explode('=', $row_data);

    $info2[$row]['id']           = $row_internal[0];
    $info2[$row]['name']         = $row_internal[1];
    $info2[$row]['description']  = $row_internal[2];



    $info[$row]['id']           = $row_data[0];
    $info[$row]['name']         = $row_data[1];
    $info[$row]['description']  = $row_data[2];


    echo 'Account ID: ' . $info[$row]['id'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Authenticated: ' . $info[$row]['name'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Response Code: ' . $info[$row]['description'] . '<br />';
    echo '<br></br>';

    echo 'Account ID: ' . $info2[$row]['id'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Authenticated: ' . $info2[$row]['name'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Response Code: ' . $info2[$row]['description'] . '<br />';
}
```

**Result for the above code :**

```
Account ID: AccountID=0
Authenticated: Authenticated=1
Response Code: ResponseCode=0


Account ID: 
Authenticated: 
Response Code:
```

What I needed was just the values for the fields like :

```
Account ID: 0
Authenticated: 1
Response Code: 0
```

Comment: Are these variables being passed via the URL ($_GET)?

Comment: I already have a response assigned to $response variable. Just need to know how to parse it effectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is a query string response, then no need to explode, there is a better tool that handles this well.

Just use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Simple one line response example:

```
$response = 'AccountID=0&Authenticated=1&ResponseCode=0&ResponseText=Success';
parse_str($response, $data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Or if the response looks like a multiline string like this, you could apply it like:

```
$response = "AccountID=1&Authenticated=1&ResponseCode=0&ResponseText=Success
AccountID=2&Authenticated=1&ResponseCode=0&ResponseText=Success
AccountID=3&Authenticated=1&ResponseCode=0&ResponseText=Success
";

$responses = explode("\n", $response);
foreach ($responses as $key => $value) {

    parse_str($value, $data);

    if(!empty($data)) {
        echo 'Account ID: '.$data['AccountID'] .'<br/>';
        echo 'Authenticated: '.$data['Authenticated'] .'<br/>';
        echo 'Response Code: '.$data['ResponseCode'] .'<br/>';
        echo 'Response Text: '.$data['ResponseText'] .'<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ghost but with that I am getting an array of items like this : Array
(
    [AccountID] => 34
    [Authenticated] => 1
    [ResponseCode] => 0
    [ResponseText] => Success
)

Comment: @mike20132013 yes, it will turn into an array, then you could treat it as such. check out my revision